# Best way to track SQL Server stored procedure timeout exceptions in SQL Server (error logs table) itself?

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to track all the SQL Server stored procedure timeout errors or any other kind of exceptions in SQL Server itself. Mostly in error logs table instead of logging it in the server side code.
I tried doing it via Sql profiler (for creating server side trace), but I dont know what options to select for SP timeout trace.

Comment: Use a server side trace

Comment: Is there any way to track it in the SQL server itself ? as in any query to be added to the SPs which would log the error in error logs table to be tracked easily.

Comment: Sure you can add custom error logging to your SP’s. You can do whatever you like. Why don’t you want to use server side traces?

Comment: I tried creating script using server side traces in Sql profiler. I have no idea what all check  boxes to select for Sql server timeout exception.Could you please help?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Could you please help me how custom logging could be done in the SQL Server stored procedures?

Comment: 1. Create a table to record the logging; 2. Edit evry single one of your stored procedure to write the table (it's often better to create a wrapper stored procedure that you call that writes to the table). Add TRY/CATCH to the prcoedures as well

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? All errors are logged _somewhere_ and you're probably just doing extra work

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thank you for your response. We don't log the SP timeout errors in Database. Thats eating our time during production issues. I thought of logging such timeout issues whenever an SP timed out and then send an email alert to the teams. Could you help me?

Comment: Timeout is usually a _client_ issue. Your SP will run forever if the client doesn't time it out and it doesn't get deadlocked. In other words, you won't be able to log timeout from within a SP, it needs to be done from whatever is calling it. I guess that's what you mean by "server side code" here - that's the only place you can record a timeout from because that's what's raising the timeout. I see have made a few conflicting statements here. I can't actually think of a way to capture timeouts on the SQL Server side because timeouts don't happen there

Comment: Are you trying to log them to troubleshoot? There are many ways to simply find long running queries https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/long-running-queries/ in fact `sp_BlitzCache` might solve a lot of problems for you. Or are you trying to log them so you can restart them? That's a very reactive way to run things. You should find the fundamental performance issues and fix them.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid You make lot of sense. Thank you for your inputs! I'll try to find the long running queries first and then try to log them.

Answer (score 0):

The time-outs (whether of Stored Procedures or SQL blocks) are NOT logged in SQL Server Error Logs. You should use Extended Events (in past SQL Profiler) to capture the following two events:

1. `rpc_completed`: to capture stored proced and
2. `sql_batch_completed`: to capture individual SQL/script batches.

Additionally/optionally you can also capture: Lock-Timeout event and Deadlock Graph events: `Lock_Timeout`: to capture lock-timeouts and `Lock_Deadlock`: to capture Deadlock locking.

Note: It's worth checking the state of indexes, as amongst other reasons, the timeouts are often caused due to missing/insufficient indexes.